# What is difference between int* pn = &n and int pn = &n in C language

Tags: c, pointers

Question about pointers.  I know in the declaration `int* pn = &n`, `pn` is initialized as a pointer to the memory address of `n`.  However, why can we not just say `int pn = &n`?  If we wrote it like that, wouldn't that be the same thing as setting the variable `pn` to the memory location of `n`?  I do not exactly understand why the `*` is necessary.

Comment: Because that's how the language is designed. It would be a mess if it worked in the way you suggest.

Comment: The compiler didn't give you a hint when you tried to compile code like this?

Comment: Such basic questions are answered by every C book. Read one.

Comment: @Olaf, I have done a lot of research and have not found anything that addresses this specific question.  Just trying to make sure I fully understand the difference.

Comment: The difference between what? A pointer and an integer? You don't need to learn "the difference", you need to learn integers (and other basic types), then pointers.

Comment: I don't understand the down & close votes, this is a pretty good question if you consider that addresses are just integers.

Comment: Exactly!  Thank you @Lundin.  That is precisely why I asked the question.  Glad for the confirmation I am asking good questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that your question boils down to: why is there a pointer type in C when addresses are really just integers? There are a few reasons for this.

- First the obvious, the address bus might be of a different size than the integer type of your system, so it might not fit inside an integer. As a side note, the `int` type is signed so it is probably unsuitable to store an address for that reason too, since addresses are usually unsigned.
- But also because we want a distinct pointer type, which cannot get wildly mixed up with plain integers. C prevents you from doing implicit conversions between integers to/from pointers. The line `int pn = &n` will not actually compile because it violates this type safety (the "simple assignment" rule). Some compilers are a bit lax about giving compiler errors for this, even though it is a C standard violation. (In GCC make sure you have `-pedantic-errors` set)

  And since we have a distinct pointer type, C also allows us to do pointer arithmetic based on the pointed-at type, which is mighty handy. For example it allows us to use pointers as if they were arrays.

Modern C introduces two new integer types that can be used to safely store addresses: `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`. These are guaranteed to be large enough to safely store an address, but you still have to use an explicit conversion to/from pointer type:

```
uintptr_t pn = (uintptr_t)&n;
```

---

(`intptr_t` is mildly useful, though there are exotic cases where you actually have negative addresses. I believe some virtual memory addressing on certain systems might use negative addresses to indicate kernel address space.)

Comment: Lundin thank you so much for this helpful information!  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

> I do not exactly understand why the * is necessary.

To differentiate between a pointer and an integer probably, because they also have different meaning and functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The *big* difference is that in the first case `pn` is a *pointer* and you can use it as such, including using array indexing and the dereference operator.

In the second case `pn` is a plain `int` variable, whose contents just happens to contain the address of `n`.

The second case is also treacherous if you're on a 64-bit system, where addresses are 64 bits (8 bytes) wide and `int` is typically 32 bits (4 bytes) wide.

---

More "graphically" is could be viewed like this:

Assuming the code

```
int n = some value;
int *p = &n;  // Make p point to n
int v = &n;  // Initialize v to the address of n
```

Then it looks something like

```
+---+      +---+
| p | ---> | n |
+---+      +---+

+---+
| v |
+---+
```

The variable `v` just sits alone, containing whatever value it was initialized with. But `p` *points* to the location of `n`.

That in reality, on the actual hardware, the contents of `p` and `v` are equal (on platforms where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)`) doesn't really matter. It's how the compiler handles these different variables that is the point (pun not intended).

Comment: This is a perfect explanation.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is to specify that `pn` is a pointer toward an `int` and not actually an `int`. The size of a pointer is not the same as the size of the object (in most cases). Go read about pointers for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `int pn = &n;` is incorrect, whenever you use & in your code c compiler understands that you are going to deal woth addresses. In other more simpler terms we can say that & is address of operator. 
In you statement you are trying to initialise a normal integer variable with the address of the another, which is not correct. When you write `&n`  compiler thinks that you are going to initialise a variable with the address of n, defenitely that variable should be a pointer because addresses cant be stored in a normal variable. Hope it'll help.